# Running script from Linux shell inside a Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

Team,
I need to execute a shell script that is within a kubernetes pod. However the call needs to come from outside the pod. Below is the script for your reference:

`echo 'Enter Namespace: '; read namespace; echo $namespace;`

`` kubectl exec -it `kubectl get po -n $namespace|grep -i podName|awk '{print $1}'` -n $namespace --- {scriptWhichNeedToExecute.sh} ``

Can anyone suggest on how to do this?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a good way. A simple option might be `cat script.sh | kubectl exec -i -- bash` but that can have weird side effects. The more correct solution would be to use a debug container but that feature is still in alpha right now.